# Performance tuning in Oracle - update same column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a query in Oracle to update the column based on same column

`UPDATE TABLE SET A = 'CG-'||A`

I HAVE THE DATA LIKE

```
COLUMN A
121
234
333
```

I NEED THE DATA LIKE

```
COLUMN A
CG-121
CG-234
CG-333
```

basically I am doing this for 30 Million records and its taking lot of time. Is there any way I can optimize this query?. If I create a Index on Column A does that improve the performance?

Comment: Unless you need to do this more than once, you might as well let it execute in a long time. Focus your tuning effort on queries that are run many times - a query that only takes 5 minutes to complete but is run 20 times a day, every day, matters more than an update that will take 8 hours, one time.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct query:

```
UPDATE TABLE
    SET A = 'CG-' || A;
```

Here are different options.

First, you can do this in batches, say 100,000 rows at a time.  This limits the size of the log.

Second, you can do a "replace" rather than update:

```
create table tempt as 
    select * from table;

truncate table "table";

insert into table ( . . . )
    select 'CG-' || A, . . . 
    from tempt;
```

Third, you can use a generated column and dispense with the update (but only in the most recent versions of Oracle).

Comment: Does adding Index on that column helps?

Comment: @beckham . . . An index will only make things worse.  You are updating all the rows, so performance is actually worse with an index.  The index has to be updated as well as the data pages.